# How racist is "nègre"?

Tags: vocabulaire, insultes

The caption "*Le Pape a Paris: Les Français aussi cons que les nègres*" from Charlie Hebdo's cover of issue n°498 (24 mai 1980),

[image: cover of issue n°498 (24 mai 1980)]

[allegedly translates](https://twitter.com/BenjaminNorton/status/553615451860008960) as follows:

> The Pope in Paris: The French are as stupid as n*gg*rs.

The [English edition of Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%C3%A8gre) describes “nègre” as equivalent to “negro”, rather than the n word, and doesn't warn about it as being offensive.

How racist is the word? Is it really on par with the n word in English?

Comment: What do you mean about "n*gg*rs, I need to replace * with 'e' to find the complete word ? Why don't write the entire words ?

Comment: This is (has become) really racist although black people use it to call themselves... it was already considered racist back in 1980 so this quote was deliberately provoking (implying the pope being racist from where I see it...)

Comment: @IndianJo the translation came from https://twitter.com/BenjaminNorton/status/553615451860008960, which used asterisks to avoid the n word.

Comment: Yes, this whole 'avoid-to-write-the-word' hypocrisy is a great way to solve all racism problems. Everyone knows that if one just doesn't use the word, he *can't be* racist. if he does, he *automatically* is. Such a simple world.

Comment: Many people seem to misunderstand this usage of the colon. On this cover “Les Français aussi cons que les nègres” is not meant to be a quote from the Pope. “Le Pape à Paris” is just a context introducer.

Comment: For what it's worth: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Niggers_of_America

Comment: @Amphiteóth I asked this question hoping to refute that person's statement.

Comment: By the way, "une tête de nègre" is the french expression for Marshmallow teacake.

Comment: See also [this](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whippet_%28biscuit%29), which contains unusual references; not French but I noted other [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate-coated_marshmallow_treats) to words which may be derived from the pastry name you mention. There is also a debate surrounding the use of such pastry name and similar, as evidenced in something like [this](http://www.bvoltaire.fr/joriskarl/france-syndrome-tete-negre,94265).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Nègre* was a popular word during the colonial empires time to name African indigenous black people.

Nowadays, it is extremely outdated (unlike the N word). In the very rare cases it is still used, it is usually deliberately offensive unless used by black people themselves, especially in in the *Négritude* movement (Aimé Césaire, Léopold Sédar Senghor).

It was used without being offensive in arts (*Art Nègre*, now usually called *Arts traditionnels africains*) and shouldn't either be taken as offensive in the cover you cite being offbeat / satirical humour.

*[Nègre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31033/n%C3%A8gre-litt%C3%A9raire/31509)* was also used to name a ghostwriter.

Answer (score 7):

Nègre est un substantif masculin (négresse au féminin) et un adjectif, désignant les Noirs.

En français, le substantif a pris avec le temps **une connotation péjorative et raciste**

---

"Nègre" is a masculine noun ("négresse"  to female) and an adjective, designating blacks people.

In French, the noun has taken over time pejorative and racist connotation.