# Nègre (littéraire)

Tags: expressions, usage

Dans une biographie d'Alphonse Daudet les auteurs disent que lui avait des **nègres littéraires**. Wikipédia en parle aussi.

Je me demande pourquoi les auteurs emploient le mot **nègre** puisqu'il a une connotation raciste et insultante et pas **prête-plume** ou **écrivain fantôme**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Les termes politiquement corrects de *prête-plume* ou *écrivain fantôme* ne sont pas aussi facilement compris que *nègre* dans ces acceptions.

La connotation raciste de « nègre » quand il désigne un écrivain a longtemps été contestée ou niée, et continue parfois de l'être. Le terme a donc été encore utilisé bien longtemps après qu'il cesse quasiment de l'être pour désigner les personnes « de couleur », et on peut donc encore le rencontrer aujourd'hui.

On peut comparer *nègre* dans son acception littéraire au mot *mongolien* dans son acception médicale. Pendant des décennies, il n'est venu à personne l'idée que *mongolien* pouvait avoir un caractère offensant, ne serait-ce que pour les habitants de Mongolie. Les deux sens étaient quasiment considérés comme deux homonymes accidentels. La prise de conscience du problème posé par ce mot a été plus précoce et aujourd'hui, on n'utilise heureusement plus que *trisomique*.

Un jour peut-être, les mots *esclave* (slave) que personne ne conteste aujourd'hui deviendra politiquement incorrect à cause de son étymologie supposée, puisque certaines sources (aujourd'hui contestées) indiquent qu'il désignait à l'origine  et de façon péjorative des individus de peuples slaves (en anglais: *Slavs*) réduits en esclavage.

Comment: J'avais une conversation aujourd'hui et j'ai utilisé nègre littéraire. Mes co-locuteurs étaient vraiment choqué d'avoir entendu ce mot. Par ailleurs,  je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi ghostwriter est bien utilisé en anglais et pas écrivain fantôme en français.

Comment: @dimitris Concernant votre question sur l'usage de « écrivain fantôme » --  Une raison à ne pas oublier est que dans ni l'une ni l'autre des deux langues ne sommes-nous tenus de calquer les idées sur l'autre et que de même dans ni l'une ni l'autre ne sommes-nous tenus de trouver de bon gout quoi que ce soit qui ait été créé dans l'autre.

Comment: L'âge de la personne employant l'expression a son importance. Quelqu'un qui a employé toute sa vie *nègre* pour désigner ces écrivains sans avoir conscience de l'aspect raciste du mot, mais simplement comme une variante spécialisée du mot *esclave* ne va pas changer du jour au lendemain ses habitudes. Personne ne s'offusque de l'utilisation du mot *bulldozer* aujourd'hui alors que son étymologie est, elle aussi, violemment associée à l'esclavage. https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2018/02/14/word-racist-roots-bulldozer/

Answer (score 5):

> Dans le domaine littéraire, le terme de « plume » ou « prête-plume »
> est employé jusqu’au xve siècle, coïncidant avec le début du
> développement du commerce triangulaire et, avec lui, de l'esclavage
> des Noirs. Ce terme est resté utilisé par les canadiens francophones.
> Ainsi, l'Office québécois de la langue française observe que le terme
> « nègre » provoque aujourd'hui des réticences en raison de sa très
> forte connotation, et suggère d'utiliser des termes plus neutres comme
> « prête-plume » et « écrivain fantôme », même s’ils sont d’un usage
> moins fréquent.
>
> Au xviiie siècle, le terme consacré était celui d’« écrivain à gage »,
> et dans le langage familier spécialisé des écrivains et des éditeurs,
> on trouve le mot « teinturier » avec le même sens. Voltaire, lui,
> utilisait le terme de « blanchisseur. »
>
> Le mot « nègre » dérange aujourd’hui à cause de sa connotation raciste
> que l’on ne retrouve pas dans d'autres langues comme l'anglais («
> ghostwriter », soit « écrivain fantôme »). On l’emploie ainsi souvent
> entre guillemets ou accompagné de l’adjectif « littéraire » et on a
> proposé des substitutions comme « écrivain privé », ou « écrivain
> sous-traitant », « rewriter », etc., mais leur emploi n’est pas
> vraiment établi. Certains préfèrent des euphémismes comme «
> collaborateur » ou « documentaliste ».
>
> Certains utilisent le mot logographe terme utilisé en Grèce pour celui
> qui rédigeait des plaidoiries pour autrui.
>
> **En 2017, une pétition lancée à l'initiative de Nelly Buffon demande le
> remplacement de cette locution dans le Dictionnaire de l'Académie
> française. En avril 2017, la délégation générale à la langue
> française et aux langues de France propose d'utiliser l'expression «
> prête-plume », recommandation confirmée par le ministère de la
> culture le 13 novembre 2017 selon un courrier adressé au CRAN.**

Source : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A8gre_litt%C3%A9raire

Aussi :

> Le «nègre littéraire» est officiellement à bannir.
>
> Le Conseil représentatif des associations noires de France explique avoir obtenu gain de cause, ce jeudi 16 novembre, auprès du ministère de la Culture pour bannir la formule «nègre littéraire». Elle doit dorénavant être remplacée par «prête-plume».

Source : http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/2017/11/17/37002-20171117ARTFIG00081-le-negre-litteraire-est-officiellement-a-bannir.php

> L'expression «nègre littéraire» officiellement remplacée par «prête-plume»
>
> DICTIONNAIRE Cette recommandation sera notamment envoyée aux médias afin qu’ils en tiennent compte et modifient leurs usages…

Source : https://www.20minutes.fr/societe/2170711-20171116-expression-negre-litteraire-officiellement-remplacee-prete-plume

> Littérature : pourquoi utilise-t-on le mot «nègre» pour désigner les écrivains fantômes ?
>
> En résumé : l’expression «nègre» pour désigner un auteur qui écrit à la place d’un autre renvoie vers l’emploi de ce même mot désormais associé à l’esclavage et qui revêt un aspect raciste.

Source : https://www.liberation.fr/checknews/2018/01/18/litterature-pourquoi-utilise-t-on-le-mot-negre-pour-designer-les-ecrivains-fantomes_1623340

Une autre expression voisine est "faire le nègre" qui doit être la forme elliptique de "faire un appel à un nègre littéraire". Toutes ces expressions sont à bannir comme l'étaient des expressions comme "travailler comme un nègre".

Comment: +1 for a great answer & +5 for each person who was shocked by your use of that word during the conversation that you mention elsewhere in a comment. Just a suggestion, but I'd mention that conversation & those justified reactions in the very beginning of your answer & include the level of intelligence, civility, and open-mindedness (based on your opinion/observations) of each of that discussion's shocked participants (& of much less, if any, importance, each of their levels of education & native languages). Albeit anecdotal, that discussion/those reactions is evidence of the best kind.

Comment: @Dimitris  With all due respect to the French ministry of culture, it's not for the government to act as a Sprachpolizei and tell people what they can and cannot say.

Answer (score 5):

Pour ajouter aux autres réponses, je propose les explications suivantes:

- Tout le monde n'adhère pas à la mouvance du politiquement correct: Ce n'est pas parce que le mot *nègre* en général a une connotation raciste qu'il faut l'éviter dans ce cas précis.
- Certains usent de la connotation raciste de *nègre* non pas pour suggérer le caractère d'esclave du prête-plume, mais plutôt pour souligner celui d'exploiteur de l'auteur prétendu.

Lorsque le lien est assumé et qu'on veut rester dans la neutralité, par exemple pour la rédaction des discours de personnages politiques, on parle plutôt de *plumes*, sans le *prête-*.